# One's complement checksum over struct with padding?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, ip

I am writing some code that uses IP/UDP packets to communicate.  I thus need to be able to calculate the checksum for both headers.  My header structures are as follows:

```
/* Internet protocol v4 header */
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ip_ver_hl;      /* ip v4, header length = 5 32 bit words */
    uint8_t ip_tos;         /* type of service */
    uint16_t ip_len;        /* total length in bytes (ip header + data) */
    uint16_t ip_id;         /* identification */
    uint16_t ip_off;        /* fragment offset field */
#define IP_DF 0x4000        /* dont fragment flag */
#define IP_MF 0x2000        /* more fragments flag */
#define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff   /* mask for fragmenting bits */
    uint8_t  ip_ttl;        /* time to live */
uint8_t  ip_proto;      /* layer 4 protocol */
uint16_t ip_checksum;   /* ip header checksum */
uint32_t ip_src;        /* ip source address */
uint32_t ip_dst;        /* ip destination addresss */
} ttev_ip_header_t;

/* Pseudo header used to calculate udp checksum */
typedef struct {
    uint32_t ip_src;        /* ip source address */
    uint32_t ip_dst;        /* ip destination addresss */
    uint8_t zero;           /* placeholder = 0 */
    uint8_t ip_proto;       /* layer 4 protocol = udp */
    uint16_t udp_len;       /* total length in bytes (header + data) */
} ttev_udp_pseudo_t;   

/* User datagram protocol header */
typedef struct {
    uint16_t udp_src_port;  /* source port */
    uint16_t udp_dst_port;  /* destination port */
    uint16_t udp_len;       /* total length in bytes (udp header + data) */
    uint16_t udp_checksum;  /* udp header/data checksum */
} ttev_udp_header_t;
```

Now my actual general checksum functions works great.  However, since the structures are not packed, aren't I open to errors since when checksumming over on of the headers, there may be padding between the structure members?  I'd like to avoid *attribute*((packed)) to maintain portability.

Is there an alternative besides checksumming each individual 16 bit group in a structure?

Answer (score 0):

The UDP and IP packet headers are structured so that they match C's alignment.  Thus, as long as `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are actually 8-bits and 16-bits wide (respectively) then there will never be any added padding and word-wise checksum over the entire structure will be just fine.

Basically, alignment means that every field starts on a boundary matching its size or the natural word size of the machine (whichever is smaller).  The structure itself is padded out to be a multiple of the largest alignment among all fields.